# Issue with asynchronous angular requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs5

How to handle asynchronous calls in angular. I know i am getting array as undefined due to asynchronous nature but how do i solve it

```
private fetchData(id){
   var array = [];
   this.httpClient.get('someUrl/'+id).subscribe((organisation)=>{
      console.log(organisation.teams);   // ['team1','team2','team3']
      organisation.teams.forEach((team)=>{
          this.httpClient/get('someUrl/'+team).subscribe((teamData)=>{
             array.push(teamData);
          })
       })
       console.log(array);    // undefined
    })
}
```

Comment: this.httpClient/get('someUrl/'+team) is that code correct?

Comment: what did you get while console logging teamData, before pushing into array?

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: maybe you can add  `if(array) {console.log(array)}` and see if it's returned as it'll only call when there's a value

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine and you are correctly using the subscribe functionality. The reason you log `undefined` is that the `console.log(array)` line is called before the get request to `'someUrl'+team` has returned a value. To check this you can move the `console.log(array)` line inside the scope of the subscription (where the `array.push(teamData)` line is).

A more modern way of writing this with less indentation is to use async/await:

```
private async fetchData(id){
   var array = [];
   let organisation = await this.httpClient.get('someUrl/'+id).toPromise();
   console.log(organisation.teams);   // ['team1','team2','team3']
   let teamData;
   organisation.teams.forEach((team)=>{
       teamData = await this.httpClient/get('someUrl/'+team).toPromise()
       array.push(teamData);
   })
   console.log(array);
}
```